# read from txt and add to treeset

Tags: java, bufferedreader, treeset

I need to read a txt file and store my data to a treeSet.

```
public class UrbanPopulationStatistics {

private Set<UrbanPopulation> popSet;
private File file;
private BufferedReader br;

public UrbanPopulationStatistics(String fileName) throws IOException {

    this.popSet = new TreeSet<>();

    readFile("population.txt");
}

private void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {


    try {
        br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
         String line;
        while ((line=br.readLine()) != null) {


            String[] array = line.split("/");

            popSet.add(new UrbanPopulation(array[0], Integer.parseInt(array[1]), Integer.parseInt(array[4])));

        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    br.close();
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    String s = popSet.toString().replaceAll(", ", "");
    return "UrbanPopulationStatistics:\n" + s.substring(1, s.length() - 1) + "\n";
}


public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    UrbanPopulationStatistics stats = new UrbanPopulationStatistics("population.txt");
    System.out.println(stats);
}

}
```

I have tried to turn what the buffered reader reads into an array and then add it into my treeSet, but I get the error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.

Comment: I may need to add, that each line in the text file has 5 elements separated by "/". I need the first element, which is a string, and the second and last - they are numbers.

Comment: What do you mean by "but that doesn't seem to work out for me"? An exception being thrown? Unexpected output?

Comment: I get an error at the popSet.add-part. it says <identifier> expected

Comment: then add the error to the question

Comment: and the way you read the file, you are skipping a line each loop you have to declare `String line="";` before the while loop, and the while condition should look like this `while ((line=br.readLine()) != null){...` and remove the this `line = br.readLine();` from inside the loop

Comment: What do you get as Exception? Perhaps you run outside the bounds of the array or you get a parse exception?

Answer (score 2):

You have an extra period after `parseInt` at `Integer.parseInt.(array[4])));`.

Be careful when writing code. Syntax errors don't show up "nicely", i.e. the error message is not very helpful in most cases. It does show you the approximate location of the error though.

Comment: Well you've made the same mistake on the other `parseInt`. Come on, pay some attention.

Comment: I did remove the period!!

Answer (score 0):

The problem with your code is you are not storing what you read from the buffer (and hence reading twice from the buffer).  You need to assign what you read in a variable to check for null as below:

```
    private void readFile(String fileName) throws IOException {

        try {
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fileName));
            String line = null;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] array = line.split("/");

                popSet.add(new UrbanPopulation(array[0], Integer.parseInt(array[1]), Integer.parseInt(array[4])));

            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            br.close();
        }
    }
```

Also I would close the BufferedReader in the finally block to avoid resource leaks.

Comment: thank you, I still get the identifier issue at the point, where I try to add the array to the treeSet

Comment: as suggested above by others, this could be because of the compilation issue (due to the extra dot in the Integer.parseInt.().  Try fixing that.  I have updated the code with the fix for the compilation error.

Comment: I updated it too. now I'm getting this message: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.

Comment: Why are you using TreeSet?  Instead try using HashSet.  If you want to use the TreeSet, UrbanPopulation should be implementing Comparable interface for the TreeSet to maintain the sorting order.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to reproduce the error using your code, but it doesn't happened. Your code is ok.

`UnsupportedOperationException` are exceptions that can happen when you try to add an element in a collection.

But `TreeSet` implements the add method.